# Remove part of a string in a Batch (.bat) file

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I need to remove part of a string so I can use the message. Tried many different ways unsuccessfully. Thanks in advance

Immagine that I have a message like this one:

```
SET MESSAGE="The key sequence '1' in 'http://www.myschema.com/dummy:dummy_PK' Keyref fails to refer to some key."
```

I need to remove this:

```
in 'http://www.myschema.com/dummy:dummy_PK' Keyref
```

And get something like this:

```
"The key sequence '1' fails to refer to some key."
```

### Do note that the text between "in" and "Keyref" is variable, meaning I have to find a way to remove the text between these 2 strings (inclusively).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `in` and `Keyref` only appear once, and `|` never appears, then:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set message="The key sequence '1' in 'http://www.myschema.com/dummy:dummy_PK' Keyref fails to refer to some key."
set "message=!message: in =|!"
set "message=!message: Keyref =|!"
for /f "delims=| tokens=1,3" %%A in ("!message!") do set "message=%%A %%B"
set message
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

SET "MESSAGE=The key sequence '1' in 'http://www.myschema.com/dummy:dummy_PK' Keyref fails to refer to some key."
SET "sFind=in 'http://www.myschema.com/dummy:dummy_PK' Keyref "
call set New=%%Message:%sFind%=%%
echo %New%
```

Comment: In theory your code works, what I forgot to say was that the:

'http://www.myschema.com/dummy:dummy_PK' is variable... Meaning that I want to remove not only the "in" and the "Keyref" but also the text between them

Comment: Does the variable text always have a URL format to it with no spaces?